# Typename passed as parameter in C++

Tags: c++, macros

My friend gave me a snipped of code asking to explain it:

```
typedef struct bia_motor {
    unsigned int attributes123;
} type_bia_motor;

typedef struct bia {
    int attributes456;
} type_bia;

type_bia_motor *constructor()
{
    return ALLOCATION(type_bia_motor);
}
```

I understand a general idea, but I cannot imagine the parameter of ALLOCATION function. I supposed this code:

```
type_bia_motor* ALLOCATION( ??? ) {
    return new type_bia_motor;
}
```

In more detail:

```
void* ALLOCATION( TYPENAME ) {
    // IF type_bia_motor IS NEEDED
        return new type_bia_motor;
    // IF type_bia IS NEEDED
        return new type_bia;
}
```

Any idea how ALLOCATION should look like?

Apparently it is (code by Marco A. & dolan):

```
ALLOCATION(X) (new X)
```

Comment: probably a macro, anything could happen.. are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Yes! Macro is a good idea! I was just wondering how it could be implemented.

Comment: Is this C++? Guessing `#define ALLOCATION(X) (new X)`. This is awful by the way.

Comment: Yes, it works. "ALLOCATION(X) (new X)". Actually I have never used macro. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is a macro:

```
#define ALLOCATION(type) (new type)

type_bia_motor *constructor()
{
    return ALLOCATION(type_bia_motor);
}
```

this would definitely work, although it's a horrible coding style and practice.

*Disclaimer: Let this just be an exercise of thought and don't ever write code like that for a serious project.*